# Displaying a foreach list in alphabetical order c#

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, alphabetical

I have a list that I'm pulling through an API, just struggling to find a way to display the output in alphabetical order.

```
@foreach (_SiriServiceDeliverySituationExchangeDeliveryPtSituationElement Situation in 
(Model.ServiceDelivery.SituationExchangeDelivery.Situations))
{   
    Alert for: @Situation.Summary.Value 
}
```

The situation.summary.value displays multiple names of a places in a list and at the moment just displays in a random order, I know I can do Enumerable.Reverse to reverse the order of the list but just can't figure out a way to do it alphabetically.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image: This is an example of how the area names are displayed]

Comment: You could just add a OrderBy() at the end of your list. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0

Comment: Hello, please show us what the data looks like you want to sort so there is a clear understanding of what you are attempting

Comment: @KarenPayne Thanks Karen, I have updated the post with a picture link.

Answer (score 0):

Import **System.Linq** and use **OrderBy()**

```
@foreach (_SiriServiceDeliverySituationExchangeDeliveryPtSituationElement Situation in 
(Model.ServiceDelivery.SituationExchangeDelivery.Situations.OrderBy(s => s.Summary.Value))
{   
    Alert for: @Situation.Summary.Value 
}
```

Check if it works!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it says 'can not use a lambda expression as  an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to order by Situations property.

**Class and mocked data**

```
public class SituationExchangeDelivery
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Situations { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Situations;

}

public class Mocked
{
    public static List<SituationExchangeDelivery> SituationExchangeList() =>
        new List<SituationExchangeDelivery>()
        {
            new SituationExchangeDelivery() {Id = 1, Situations = "Newsome"},
            new SituationExchangeDelivery() {Id = 2, Situations = "Emley"},
            new SituationExchangeDelivery() {Id = 3, Situations = "Outwood"},
            new SituationExchangeDelivery() {Id = 4, Situations = "Stourton"}
        };
```

Usage

```
IOrderedEnumerable<SituationExchangeDelivery> data =
    Mocked.SituationExchangeList()
        .OrderBy(item => item.Situations);

foreach (var delivery in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(delivery);
}
```

Or

```
List<SituationExchangeDelivery> data =
    Mocked.SituationExchangeList()
        .OrderBy(item => item.Situations).ToList();

foreach (var delivery in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(delivery);
}
```

**Output**

```
Emley
Newsome
Outwood
Stourton
```

Comment: Thanks Karen, I like the idea you've gone with but its a constantly updating APi so its not just specific to them area names.

Comment: @Develop that is why I asked for more details rather than just an image. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)